# Maximum value of a vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-bundles

If a,b,c are unit vectors , then we have to know $|a-b|^2$$+|b-c|^2$$+|c-a|^2$ does not exceed .

I tried it a lot , but not able to get how to start it .

Comment: Your question has some crucial info missing. Does not exceed *what*?

Comment: It is also missing the part where you describe what the "a lot" of things you tried is.

Comment: @PVanchinathan there is a numerical value through which the above system of vectors does not exceed.

Comment: @IanMiller I tried by putting values of a ,b,c and I got the maximum value as 8 but answer is 9

Comment: And what is $I?$

Comment: @gammatester mod

Comment: @koolman This is not a guess and check type question where you can just substitute in numbers. You need to be able to prove it is true for any possible numbers. You would be there a lot time if you are going to guess and check every possible number. What other strategies have you tried?

Comment: @IanMiller i am not getting any other stratergies

Comment: Well here is a start: Assuming mod means the norm $|| a -b ||$ you get  via triangle inequality  from $|| a -b ||^2 \le (|| a|| + ||b ||)^2 = 2^2 = 4$ the upper bound $3\times 4 =12$. If you want the answer $9$ you have to use better estimates.

Comment: @gammatester what do you mean by upper bound

Comment: *does not exceed*, is *less than or equal*, $\le$ etc

Comment: @gammatester and how can I do better estimates

Comment: @koolman If English isn't you native language please let us know so we use simpler vocabulary (or give more detail).

Comment: @IanMiller yeah, you are correct

Comment: See my answer for a solution. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $||\mathbf{a}||^2=\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{a}\rangle$ and the linearity properties of the inner product (if you don't want this you may just expand on components) you may prove:

$||\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}||^2+||\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}||^2+||\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{c}||^2+||\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{a}||^2=3(||\mathbf{a}||^2+||\mathbf{b}||^2+||\mathbf{c}||^2)=9$

since you said that $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are on the unit circle.

So:

$||\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}||^2+||\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{c}||^2+||\mathbf{c}-\mathbf{a}||^2=9-||\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}||^2\le9$

Equality is attained when $\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}=0$, that is when $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ form an equilateral triangle on the unit circle.

EDIT: to prove the last statement at OP's request:

If $\theta$ is the angle between two of the vectors (say $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$) then:

$\cos\theta=\frac{\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\rangle}{||\mathbf{a}||\cdot||\mathbf{b}||}=\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\rangle$
since $||\mathbf{a}||=||\mathbf{b}||=1$

From $\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}=0$ we get $\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}=-\mathbf{c}$ so $||\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}||=||\mathbf{c}||=1$

Now:

$1=||\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}||^2=||\mathbf{a}||^2+||\mathbf{b}||^2+2\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\rangle=2+2\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\rangle$

$\cos\theta=\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\rangle=-\frac{1}{2}$

so

$\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}=120^{\circ}$

The angle between any two vectors is $120^{\circ}$, so the vectors form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: How you write the first relation

Comment: For example: $||\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}||^2=<\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c},\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}>=<\mathbf{a},\mathbf{a}>+<\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}>+<\mathbf{a},\mathbf{c}>+<\mathbf{b},\mathbf{a}>+<\mathbf{b},\mathbf{b}>+<\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}>+<\mathbf{c},\mathbf{a}>+<\mathbf{c},\mathbf{b}>+<\mathbf{c},\mathbf{c}>=||\mathbf{a}||^2+||\mathbf{b}||^2+||\mathbf{c}||^2+2<\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}>+2<\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}>+2<\mathbf{c},\mathbf{a}>$

Comment: what do you mean by $<,>$

Comment: Inner/dot product of two vectors [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) or [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space). You might write it as $<\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}>$ or simply $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}$. You didn't specify whether you work with vectors, complex numbers or whatever else, so I don't know the notations you use.

Comment: Thank you , great work . My last doubt is how a+b+c =0 means an equilateral triangle

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your last question. It has to do with the definition of the cosine in terms of the dot product.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

I don't know from your question if you are doing [2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_space) vectors or [3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space) vectors (or more). I will assume 2D (the reasoning doesn't change for higher dimensions.

Geometrically $||a-b||$ is the length between the 'points' $a$ and $b$ on the [Cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).

So $||a-b||^2$ is the square of the distance between the 'points'.

So you want to arrange three points on the plane so that the square of the distance between each pair of points is a maximum.

See if you can find an arrangement such that the square of the distances between all the points is 9. Then prove that any other arrangement is smaller.

Comment: Is this an hit and trial method